# JSON byte array value changed in webservice

Tags: c#, android, json, arrays, jsonserializer

I'm trying to pass byte array in json via web service. When i try to Deserialize the JSON the byte array value changed to unknow value.

For an example.
My byte value when i try to pass to webservice using android.
**Code**

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
try {
object.put("WayBillNo", bill);
object.put("ReceiverSignature", image);
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Image**
[image]

WebService when trying to serialize the JSON. (C#)

**Code**

```
payloadObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>( encryptedJson );
```

**Image**
[image: image2]

Receiversingnature value change in web service.Any advice/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which converts binary data to a string.

```
byte [] image = array;
String stringToStore = new String(Base64.encode(image));
```